# XQuery negate regex

Tags: regex, oracle, xquery

Im searching for a way to negate a regular expression in xquery.
Using Oracle with the XMLQuery function.

Ill give an example first:

```
XMLQuery(
    'for $number in ("2a2", "32", "1234", "12", "32a3", "")
    where ora:matches($number,"^[0-9]{4}$")

    return xs:integer($number)'
    passing xml RETURNING CONTENT
    )
```

this works perfect except one thing. I want to get the exact opposite of entries which do not match the pattern.

I tried

```
where fn:not(ora:matches($number,"^[0-9]{4}$"))
where ora:matches($number,"^[0-9]{4}$") = false()
where ora:matches($number,"^[0-9]{4}$") = fn:false()
```

which all give me this

ORA-01722: Ungültige Zahl
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number" 
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: I think Oracle regex supports look-arounds. Try `^(?![0-9]{4}$).*$`.

Comment: does not give me an error, but neither returns me the elements ("2a2", "32", "12", "32a3", "") that do not match

Comment: Did you specify `return $number`? You cast the value to integer in the original code with `xs:integer()`.

Comment: no it should be treated as a string for the function ora:matches takes strings as parameters (http://docs.oracle.com/html/B28369_04/xdb_xquery.htm). and the cast before returning is just for displaying it not as a large string like "7682124953876"

Comment: By negating, you filter all numbers and try to cast non-numbers. I'd propose this is expected behavior.

Comment: @user5334993, Good question! See my answer for a simple and efficient solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Just use this pure XPath 2.0 expression** (XPath 2.0 is a proper subset of XQuery):

```
("2a2", "32", "1234", "12", "32a3", "12345", "")
                      [not(matches(., "^[0-9]{4}$"))]
```

**When this expression is evaluated** (in XQuery, XSLT 2+ or any standalone XPath/XQuery interpreter tool), **the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
2a2 32 12 32a3 12345
```

**One can further simplify this**:

```
("2a2", "32", "1234", "12", "32a3", "12345", "")
                      [not(matches(., "^\d{4}$"))]
```

Answer (score 0):

The negation of `^[0-9]{4}$` could be written as `^[0-9]{0,3}$|^[0-9]{0,3}[^0-9]|^[0-9]{4}.`

- `^[0-9]{0,3}$` will match a number that is too short.
- `^[0-9]{0,3}[^0-9]` will match a string that contains a non-digit in the first four characters.
- `^[0-9]{4}.` will match a string that starts with four digits, but is too long.